# Delete Axis from chart

Tags: vba, charts, powerpoint, axis

There seems to be a lot of information on how to ADD axis to chart however, theres not much information available if you want to DELETE/REMOVE axis from a chart.

So I have a 100% stack bar chart.

I would like to delete/remove the X axis (left to right).

I imagined that it would be something as simple as....

```
 Chart.HasAxis(xlCategory) = False
```

But I get a "can't assign function call"

Not sure what code would turn the x axis off?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe post more of your code if this still doesn't work -- unless you have previously declared `Chart` as a variable and assigned a `Chart` to it (another problem is potentially using reserved/semi-reserved keywords for variable names), the statement you provide is at best pseudo-syntax.

What you're doing should work, fundamentally, assigning a boolean to something like `ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes(1).Chart.HasAxis(xlCategory) = _boolean_` should definitely work.

For example create a presentation with one slide, delete all shapes/placeholders, and then insert a stacked bar 100% chart.    Then run this macro:

```
Sub Test()
Dim cht As Chart
Dim sld As Slide
Dim pres As Presentation

    Set pres = ActivePresentation
    Set sld = pres.Slides(1)
    Set cht = sld.Shapes(1).Chart

    If MsgBox("Should this chart have a visible category axis?", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
        cht.HasAxis(xlCategory) = True
    Else:
        cht.HasAxis(xlCategory) = False
    End If
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for the effort, very informative! I managed to find this little line which worked - Chart.Axes(xlValue, 1).Delete() not sure why the boolean method didnt work for me..